# Handling Concurrent requests for a Bank Transaction in the real world

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

The classic bank balance problem where I am trying to execute multiple deposit/withdrawal transactions on an account.

I have synchronized the two methods in the account class and the account balance is 500 at the end of the execution only if I join all the threads (wait for execution to finish.)

So i am considering a real world scenario where each request spawns a new thread executes the transaction and return s the balance.Would the balance being reported each time be incorrect as there are other threads operating on the same account ?

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;


 class Account {

    private int balance = 0;


    Account(int bal){
        this.balance =bal;
    }

    public int getBal() {
        return balance;
    }


    public synchronized void withdraw(int bal){
       balance = balance - bal;
   }

     public  synchronized void deposit(int bal){
            balance = balance + bal;
        }
     }

public class TransactionManagerNaiveSync implements Runnable {

    Account account;

    public TransactionManagerNaiveSync(Account a){
     this.account = a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
         Account a1 = new Account(500);
        TransactionManagerNaiveSync t1 = new TransactionManagerNaiveSync(a1);

        List<Thread> thread = new ArrayList<Thread>();
        for(int i=0;i < 300;i++) thread.add(new Thread(t1));
        for(int i=0;i < 300;i++) thread.get(i).start();
        for(int i=0;i < 300;i++){
            try {
                thread.get(i).join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(" Account Balance in the end : "+ a1.getBal());
        System.out.println(" Time Taken : "+(end - start));
    }



    @Override
    public void run() {

        //for(int i=0;i < 100;i++)
        //{
            account.deposit(10);
            System.out.println(""+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" Account Balance after deposit : "+account.getBal());
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            account.withdraw(10);
            System.out.println(""+Thread.currentThread().getId()+" Account Balance after withdrawal : "+account.getBal());
        //}

    }

}
```

Comment: Your example would be more interesting if (a) there was a rule that no thread is ever allowed to see a negative balance, and (b) the threads would withdraw money first, then pause, and then deposit money.

Comment: yes that correct..it would be more interesting or more confusing in my case :D . All I am wondering is how does this work in the real world.

Answer (score 4):

The balance is potentially incorrect as you are not synchronizing `Account.getBal()`, meaning that you might not get an up-to-date value, owing to memory visibility guarantees not being available for non-synchronized access to variables updated by multiple threads.

Simply mark the method `synchronized`.

It would also be easier (and almost certainly more performant) if you stored the balance as an `AtomicInteger` instead of `int`, since you would not need to `synchronize` at all then.

Comment: Yes that is true, But I would have to synchronize at the request level right? not just account level as balance needs to locked at the request level?

Answer (score 2):

> I have synchronized the two methods...
>
> So i am considering a real world scenario... Would the balance being reported each time be incorrect as there are other threads operating on the same account ?

Well, that depends on what you mean by "the correct balance".  What *is* the correct balance if some other thread can change it between the time when you ask for it and the time when you print it?

In a multithreaded environment, different ideas of what "correct" means are known as *consistency models*.

One consistency model that is very easy to understand is called *quiescent consistency*.  If your program is quiescently consistent, that means that the balance will be correct at any moment when all of the threads are simultaneously idle (here, "idle" means doing anything that does not affect the balance).  It's easy to define, but it could be tricky to test:  What if no such moment ever occurs?

Another consistency model is called *linearizability*.  A simplistic definition of linearizability says that your program is linearizable if the balance is "correct" every time, and at the *exact instant*, when one of your threads releases a lock that is used to protect the balance.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
@GuardedBy("this")

private int balance = 0;
```